# Using Craft to render frontend pages in addition to using it headless

Tags: headless

I’m looking to create a craft site for some digital storytelling pieces. The pages will be curated by various people within my team. But I also like the idea of using the CMS to push separate content within the cms, to things other than the website. This would give us a lot of flexibility. Can you use Craft to render the front pages using twig as normal, and additionally run it in headless mode? Or if i want the benefit of using it as a headless CMS would I instead have to render the frontend site using a static site generator, like Gatsbyjs? What are my options if I want to use it both ways?

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! Craft works really well like this. You can use twig to render your website, then either [element api](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api) or graph QL (built in to craft 3.3) to open up your data to other applications.

I run several sites like this where I’ve opened up various parts of the content for external use, e.g. the news feed for use in an app.